# Updating mongodb with java driver takes forever?

Tags: java, mongodb, csv

So this is the case: I have a program that takes two large csv-files, finds the diffs and then sends a array list to a method that is supposed to update the mongodb with the lines from the array. The problem is the updates are taking forever. A test case with 5000 updates takes 36 minutes. Is this normal?

the `update(List<String> changes)`-method something like this:

```
mongoClient = new MongoClient(ip);
db = mongoClient.getDB("foo");
collection = db.getCollection("bar");

//for each line of change
for (String s : changes) {
    //splits the csv-lines on ;
    String[] fields = s.split(";");

    //identifies wich document in the database to be updated
    long id = Long.parseLong(fields[0]);
    BasicDBObject sq = new BasicDBObject().append("organizationNumber",id);

    //creates a new unit-object, that is converted to JSON and then inserted into the database.
    Unit u = new Unit(fields);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String jsonObj = gson.toJson(u);
    DBObject objectToUpdate = collection.findOne(sq);
    DBObject newObject = (DBObject) JSON.parse(jsonObj);

    if(objectToUpdate != null){
        objectToUpdate.putAll(newObject);
        collection.save(objectToUpdate);
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the stats on the server? It seems like it shouldn't take that long with a reasonable configuration.

Comment: @WiredPrairie I just installed it out of the box, what am I looking for? This is my first time using mongo, you see.

Comment: Is `organizationNumber` indexed?

Comment: What does `stats` return? http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.stats/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are taking extra steps to update.
You don't need to parse JSONs manually and you don't have to do the query-then-update when you can just do an update with a "where" clause in a single step.

Something like this:

```
BasicDBObject query= new BasicDBObject().append("organizationNumber",id);
Unit unit = new Unit(fields);
BasicDBObject unitDB= new BasicDBObject().append("someField",unit.getSomeField()).append("otherField",unit.getOtherField());
collection.update(query,unitDB);
```

Where `query` specifies the "where" clause and `unitDB` specifies the fields that need to be updated.

Comment: While that would improve the algorithm, it still seems like it's super slow for some other reason. 5000 find and updates in 36 minutes...that's not many on reasonable hardware.

Comment: Do you have too many indexes? Indexes make inserts significantly slower. Try dropping the indexes if you have them and see if that makes any difference.